# WordPress Get the Page ID outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the page ID before starting the loop in WordPress. I am using

```
$page = get_query_var('page_id');
```

Apparently, it returns nothing.

I just want to check a page for its ID and add a class to `<body>` tag based on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351038/get-the-current-page-id-inside-wordpress-plugin-page/

Answer (score 160, accepted):

If you're using pretty permalinks, `get_query_var('page_id')` won't work.

Instead, get the queried object ID <strike>from the global `$wp_query`</strike>:

```
// Since 3.1 - recommended!
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();


// "Dirty" pre 3.1
global $wp_query;

$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id     = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

Comment: Perfect for pretty permalinks. I Used global $post; echo $post->ID;  But not worked that.  Thanks!

Comment: `get_queried_object_id();` return 0 for me. I think that the problem is that i'm calling it after a custom query. I want de actual page Id.

Comment: Strange, `get_queried_object();` didn't work for me, but `$wp_query->get_queried_object();` does... I took a look at the `get_queried_object();` and it is the same as doing the latter.

Comment: Might be your variable scope - have you overridden `$wp_query` with a custom query?

Comment: Note that get_queried_object_id() returns the category ID if on a category page, since there is no page ID.

Answer (score 10):

You can also create a generic function to get the ID of the post, whether its outside or inside the loop (handles both the cases):

```
<?php

/**
 * @uses WP_Query
 * @uses get_queried_object()
 * @see get_the_ID()
 * @return int
 */
function get_the_post_id() {
  if (in_the_loop()) {
       $post_id = get_the_ID();
  } else {
       global $wp_query;
       $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
         }
  return $post_id;
} ?>
```

And simply do:

```
$page_id = get_the_post_id();
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this global $post instead:

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

Comment: This will only work after the loop, not before, since `$post` is initialized when starting "the loop".

Comment: @ChristianDavén - this is not true. This code works on beginning of the page.php

Answer (score 4):

If you by any means searched this topic because of the post page (index page alternative when using static front page), then the right answer is this:

```
if (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page') {
    $page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
    echo get_the_title($page_id);
}
```

(taken from [Forrst | Echo WordPress "Posts Page" title - Some code from tammyhart](http://forrst.com/posts/Echo_WordPress_Posts_Page_title-dvH))

Answer (score 2):

I have done it in the following way and it has worked perfectly for me.

First declared a global variable in the header.php, assigning the ID of the post or page before it changes, since the LOOP assigns it the ID of the last entry shown:

`$GLOBALS['pageid] = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();`

And to use anywhere in the template, example in the footer.php:

`echo $GLOBALS['pageid];`

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a page and this does not work:

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
```

you can try to build the permalink manually with PHP so you can lookup the post ID:

```
// get or make permalink
$url = !empty(get_the_permalink()) ? get_the_permalink() : (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$permalink = strtok($url, '?');

// get post_id using url/permalink
$post_id = url_to_postid($url);

// want the post or postmeta? use get_post() or get_post_meta()
$post = get_post($post_id);
$postmeta = get_post_meta($post_id);
```

It may not catch every possible permalink (especially since I'm stripping out the query string), but you can modify it to fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`is_page($page_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) outside the loop to check.

Comment: I dont want to check a page, I want to get the ID of current page.

Comment: @atif are you sure a page ID is in fact being passed? You don't happen to be on the front page?

Answer (score 0):

This function get id off a page current.

```
get_the_ID();
```

Comment: um...this only works if you're [in the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID):
_Returns the numeric ID of the current post. **This tag must be within The Loop.**_

Comment: @drzaus Actually this does work outside the loop... Check it out.

Comment: @hitautodestruct while you are technically correct that it _could_ work outside the loop, it's not a reliable usage -- this is from personal experience as well looking at the source code.  The underlying method [get_post](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L417) happens to use `$GLOBALS['post']`, which could have been populated at some point but there's no guarantee _unless/until_ you're in the loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351038/get-the-current-page-id-inside-wordpress-plugin-page/

Answer (score 0):

Use below two lines of code to get current page or post ID

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

Answer (score -3):

This is the correct code.

```
echo $post->ID;
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are out of the Loop of WordPress you can not use any of the method of wordpress so you must use pure php.

You can use this code. And sure will help you :)

```
$page_id = @$_GET['page_id'];

if (!is_numeric($page_id)) {
    // Then the uri must be in friendly format aka /my_domain/category/onepage/
    // Try this
    //$path = '/www/public_html/index.php/';
    ///$path = '/my_domain/category/onepage/';
    $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // Clean the uri
    //$path = str_replace('/', '', $page);
    $path = str_replace('.php', '', $path);
    //$path = str_replace('?s=', '', $path);
    $path = $path ? $path : 'default';

    $path_len = strlen($path);
    $last_char = substr($path, $path_len -1);
    //echo $last_char;
    $has_slash = strpos($last_char, "/");
    //echo $has_slash;
    if ($has_slash === 0) :
        $path = substr($path, 0, $path_len -1);
    elseif ($has_slash === null) :
        $path = substr($path, 0, $path_len);
    endif;
    //echo "path: ".$path; // '/www/public_html/index'
    $page = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
    echo "page: ".$page; // 'index'
}

$my_page_id = 31;
$my_page = 'mypage';

//echo "page: ".$page;
//echo "page_id ".$page_id;
if($page_id == $my_page_id || $page == $my_page) 
{
    // your stuff....
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Maybe.. Could you please give more details about this and show me your solution?

Comment: you wrote 50 lines of code to get the variable that already exists in `$post->ID`. Even if you're not in the loop, you can use many, many Wordpress functions. Just not the few that must be used in the loop.

Comment: Well if you remove the commented code, i wrote 20 lines. Those lines saved my day in the meantine process of learning wordpress. You wrote 3 lines but you don't apport any solution to the OP question when you are outside the loop.