# How to display content from a child page within a hierarchial custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I have a hierarchical custom post type.  It has 6 pages, and each page has 3 child pages.

When viewing one of the 6 pages, I need to display content (a title and excerpt) from each of its 3 child/descendent pages.

Here is my current loop:

```
<?php if(have_posts()):?>
    <?php query_posts('&post_type=how-we-do-it&post_parent=0');?>
    <?php while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
    <?php $color = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pointb_how-we-do-it-color', true ); ?>
      <div class="section">
          <div class="title">
            <h1 style="background:<?php echo $color;?> !important;">
              <?php the_title();?>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="how-<?php the_slug();?>">the summary here. and here is child content:
                <div class="child">child content should be here.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

I have tried numerous different approaches to try and accomplish what I need, but none of them work within the custom post type.  Here are some of the various methods I have tried:

I tried the suggested code on this page: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-child-pages-title-amp-content-on-parent-page

I also tried the following code:

```
$pageChildren = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID');
if ( $pageChildren ) {
  foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
    echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">'. $pageChild->post_title.'</a></h2>
';
    if ($pageChild->post_excerpt){
      echo ''.$pageChild->post_excerpt.'

';
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a number of other methods that I didn't bother saving, so I can't show them.

I'm at the point where I am getting frustrated with this and thought I'd throw it out here to get some fresh perspectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some comments from MarZab above, I got thinking about the post ID.

I made the following tweak to the block of code I originally posted above, and now it works perfectly:

```
$pageChildren = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID');
```

Is now:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();            
$pageChildren = get_posts( 'post_type=how-we-do-it&echo=0&post_parent='.$post_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your first sample is that you call `if(have_posts())` before you reconstruct the query.

The second sample has a dangling `'` after $post->ID.

Try this:

```
$pageChildren = get_posts( 'post_type=how-we-do-it&post_parent='.$post->ID );
```

Comment: I noticed the dangling ' but the code still doesn't work. It returns child posts from the top level "Page" post type, but not child pages of the current post ID in the custom post type.

Comment: also, I recommend you change the post_name to how_we_do_it since you might run into problems

Comment: I forgot so say that I already tried what you suggested I should try. It returns a list of ALL pages in the post type. Even child pages of the other pages. It needs to be be JUST the child page of the CURRENT page.

Comment: that probably means that $post->ID isn't set.

Comment: You have to be inside the loop with $post set. It's not set by default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127385/wordpress-get-the-page-id-outside-the-loop get_queried_object_id()