# Wordpress underscores base theme won't show featured images

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to use Underscores for building themes in the future. I was trying to build up the posts list in content-page.php and noticed there is no added featured images line. I would like to make my featured image show up under the title and such.

I deleted the comments from the part in function.php where it makes sure the featured image is supported;

```
      <?php
/**
 * Sophie functions and definitions
 *
 * @package Sophie
 */

/**
 * Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 */
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 640; /* pixels */
}


if ( ! function_exists( 'sophie_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
function sophie_setup() {

    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
     * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
     * If you're building a theme based on Sophie, use a find and replace
     * to change 'sophie' to the name of your theme in all the template files
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'sophie', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );


    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'sophie' ),
    ) );

    // Enable support for Post Formats.
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'image', 'video', 'quote', 'link' ) );

    // Setup the WordPress core custom background feature.
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'sophie_custom_background_args', array(
        'default-color' => 'ffffff',
        'default-image' => '',
    ) ) );

    // Enable support for HTML5 markup.
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'search-form', 'comment-form', ) );
}
endif; // sophie_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sophie_setup' );

/**
 * Register widgetized area and update sidebar with default widgets.
 */
function sophie_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'sophie' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sophie_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function sophie_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sophie-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sophie-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sophie-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sophie_scripts' );

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
//require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
```

And then I added a line to my content-page.php which became this;

```
  <?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying page content in page.php
 *
 * @package Sophie
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'sophie' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'sophie' ), '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="edit-link">', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Now I have 'some' wordpress knowledge and this always worked for me in the past. Why isn't it showing up now? There is of course a featured image uploaded at the posts page and this featured image shows up when I use another theme that already supports them.

Is there a step that I forgot?

This is in my page.php;

```
 get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you aware that you're missing `
    }
endif;` at the end of your functions.php?

Comment: I did not include the whole functions.php file, just a bit of it. I'll add everything if that helps.

Comment: My bet; I now see that your functions.php contains more than i noticed before, so the `} endif;` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

On the [function reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) of the_post_thumbnail() i found the following:

> This tag must be used within The Loop. Use get_the_post_thumbnail($id,
>   $size, $attr ) instead to get the featured image for any post.

Since there is no loop in your content-page.php you will have to use the proposed alternative `get_the_post_thumbnail()`.

All parameters for this function are optional, so I guess it will work out of the box, but if it doesn't you can try

```
get_the_post_thumbnail(get_queried_object_id());
```

See [this stack-exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127776/2019157) answer for reference.

Edit:

If you want to place content-page.php in the loop use this code before the first article tag:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

And this code right after the article closign tag:

```
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is taken from the twentythirteen page.php.

One other thing:
Are you sure that your file has to be named content-page.php and not just page.php?

Comment: I tried both you suggested but it didn't work sadly. I added  <?php get_the_post_thumbnail() ?>  and later tried replacing it with  <?php get_the_post_thumbnail(get_queried_object_id()); ?> but both didn't work. If this is supposed to work in a loop, is it possible to add the loop to the content-page.php?

Comment: @Kelly I modified my answer because of the code blocks.

Comment: Well this is in my page.php *added to first post* and I thought that meant I had to look for the things in the content-page.php

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

in the loop.

Like this:

```
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php



                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            ?>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
```