# Wordpress/WC - Update Post/Product Meta Before Page loads

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

I am trying to create the functionality in my WooCommerce store to update the stock quantity of items as they are clicked on / their product page is loaded based on an external database and API.  I have successfully created the function using a hook like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'update_product_stock');
function update_product_stock(){
  global $product;
  $sku = $product -> get_sku();
  //code for updating based on $sku
}
```

So, when the page for a product loads, this correctly changes the stock amount for the product. The problem is, this change is not reflected as the page is loaded/rendered. The page must be refreshed or re-visited for the new stock amount to be shown. I have also tried to use the 'init' hook and the 'template_redirect' hook, but these do not allow me access to to the product to get the id/sku/other info to send to the the API for data retrieval.

Does anyone know of a way for me to get the item details of a product, update the post meta (I am using wc_update_product_stock()), and have those changes reflected on a page view without having to reload? I think I will eventually also have to implement this on a search results page, but I want to get this sorted first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was ultimately able to get the desired functionality that I'll demonstrate here if anyone else ends up needing something similar.

```
//this hook runs before the page/product loop
add_action('storefront_before_site', 'update_product_stock');

function update_product_stock(){
  //since this now runs before the standard post loop,
  //need a different way to access the post.
  //use page id to differentiate between products and other shop pages.
  $page_id = get_queried_object_id();

  //my code for fetching stock here
  $stock_num_to_set = determine_new_stock();

  $product = new WC_Product($page_id);

  //check that the page is indeed a product page 
  //(i use the sku, use your own preferred method)
  $product_sku = get_post_meta($page_id, '_sku', true);

  if($product_sku){
    //update using woocommerce product update.
    //now this is the info that will be fetched as the post is loaded normally
    wc_update_product_stock($product, $stock_num_to_set);
  }
}
```

Thanks to this user for their info on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127776/6581190